# Excel VBA : Find out which row has filter enabled

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking at various options in VBA to find out the row number in a worksheet that has filter enabled.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = True Then
```

The above line checks only if the sheet contains filters, but I need to know which row number has the filters on.

Answer (score 1):

This should do your job.

```
 Sub test()

    Dim rngRange        As range

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Set rngRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilter.range
        MsgBox "Address of Filter: " & rngRange.Address & Chr(10) _
                & "Row Number is: " & rngRange.Row, vbOKOnly
    End If

    Set rngRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight answer to your question:

```
Function CheckWhichRowHasFilter(r As range)
For Each rowi In r.Rows' Dim rowi As range
Set pa = rowi.Parent.AutoFilter'Dim pa As AutoFilter
If pa.FilterMode = True Then
  CheckWhichRowHasFilter = pa.range.Address
    Exit For
End If
Next rowi
End Function
```

This is how to iterate through Filters. The Property you want to check is Filter.On

```
Sub IterateThroughFilters()
Dim r As range
Set r = Selection
Dim rc As range
For Each rc In r.Columns
   If Not rc.Parent.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
    Set currentColumnFilter = rc.Parent.AutoFilter ' Filteraddress: = currentColumnFilter.range.Address
       Dim ccf As filters
       Set ccf = currentColumnFilter.filters
         Dim cf1 As filter
         Set cf1 = ccf(1) 'onebased index
             If cf1.On Then 'Here you check if filter is on

                cfc1 = cf1.Criteria1(1)
                cfc2 = cf1.Criteria1(2)
                cfc3 = cf1.Criteria1(3)
            End If
   End If

Next rc

End Sub
```

Comment: why do you need to iterate 'for each' loop to find out autofilter?

Comment: I think he is interested about which filters are on. Each row could have some filters on and some off. Its not clear if he wants to iterate through row columns to find them.

Comment: Maximum one filter can be applied on one worksheet. so ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).AutoFilter.range will do the job.